# Filter a algebraic datatype list

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I want to filter an algebraic datatype list in haskell. So for instance:

```
data Both = Foo Int Int
            | Bar Int
```

If I have this datatype I want to filter out the Foos. This function should return only Foos:

```
sortFoos :: [Both] -> [Both]
```

I just can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What you want to do falls afoul of [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/). Why not use `[Both] -> [(Int, Int)]` instead?

Comment: I support Jo's comment. Another approach using prisms, `makePrisms ''Both; filter (is _Bar)` or `mapMaybe (preview _Bar)` to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the filtering function using pattern matching:

```
skipFoo (Foo _ _) = False
skipFoo _ = True
```

then pass it to [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
filter skipFoo [Foo 1 2, Bar 3]  -- returns [Bar 3]
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I was having trouble why my pattern matching went wrong, but I never declared skipFoo _ = True like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
[(Bar i) | (Bar i) <- ls]
```